# MVC5 combine db .Include with OrderBy

Tags: asp.net, include, sql-order-by

In my controller I'm including Balances and RZiS like this

```
Analysis1Full analysis1Full = db.Analysis1Full
                                .Include(u => u.Balance)
                                .Include(r => r.RZiS)
                                .SingleOrDefault(u => u.Analysis1FullId == id);
//enter code here
```

it gives me right object. The point is that I want to sort Balance by string filed (Year). But it gives me an error:

```
Analysis1Full analysis1Full = db.Analysis1Full
                                .Include(u => u.Balance.OrderBy(y => y.Year))
                                .Include(r => r.RZiS)
                                .SingleOrDefault(i => i.Analysis1FullId == id);
```

**Error:**

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the exception is thrown is simply because it is designed this way. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), the *Include()* only *Specifies the related objects to include in the query results.*

To have the children in an order, you can add an *OrderBy()* when accessing them or you'd need to load them in a different query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this ... it is working

```
Analysis1Full analysis1Full = db.Analysis1Full.Find(id);

        analysis1Full.Balance = db.Balances.Where(t=>t.Analysis1FullId == analysis1Full.Analysis1FullId).OrderBy(y=>y.Year).ToList();
        analysis1Full.RZiS = db.RZiS.Where(t => t.Analysis1FullId == analysis1Full.Analysis1FullId).OrderBy(y => y.Year).ToList();
```

do you think it's good approach ?

Comment: It's fine, just keep in mind that this way you'll trigger multiple calls to the DB.

Comment: So is there any way to do it in one query ?

Comment: If you want one query only, just get the item without ordering (as you did before) and order the balances when you access that property. This way sorting will happen in memory - this solution has the downside on performance if you have huge objects. So it's a tradeoff situation and you'd need to pick the way which works best for you.